# c2664 in Visual Studio 2012 when using make_pair

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, std-pair

I dig up an old project and wanted to compile it, but received several errors, a few of those being a c2664:

```
error C2664: 'std::make_pair' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CUser *' to 'CUser *&&'
error C2664: 'std::make_pair' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned long' to ' unsigned long &&'
```

The relevant code parts are:

```
//typedef for the userdata map
typedef std::map<unsigned long, std::pair<CUser*,userstatus*>> UserDataMapType;
//...
Inc::incret CUserManager::AddUser(unsigned long ID, CUser* pUser, userstatus* pUserStatus)
{
    //...
    std::pair<UserDataMapType::iterator, bool> ret = m_mapUserData.insert(std::make_pair<unsigned long, std::pair<CUser*, userstatus*>>(ID, std::make_pair<CUser*, userstatus*>(pUser, pUserStatus)));
    //...
}
```

I tried to make the function parameters `const`, but that did not help.

It did compile just fine in VS2010.

Please help me find what causes this and how to solve it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`make_pair()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) has been changed in VS2012 to support a new C++11 feature called *move semantics* and I suspect that explicitly specifying the types for `make_pair()` is getting in the way.

Remember that `make_pair()` does not need any template parameters to be explicitly specified. It deduces them from the type of each argument.

Try removing the explicit template arguments from both calls to `make_pair()` like so...

```
std::pair<UserDataMapType::iterator, bool> ret = m_mapUserData.insert(std::make_pair(ID, std::make_pair(pUser, pUserStatus)));
```

Explicitly providing them like this would have worked fine pre-VS2012 because of a new C++11 feature added called [*move semantics*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/can-someone-please-explain-move-semantics-to-me). You'll want to read up on that subject later since you have a shiny new compiler that supports it.